# Trouble implementing stopwords in nltk

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

After importing stopwords from the corpus, I downloaded all files from nltk.download() and then

```
#reading from a .txt file

list = []
with open("positive.txt", "r") as file:
        for words in file:
            words = words.strip()
            list.append(words)

#tokenizing words

pos_words = []
for i in list:
    pos_words.append(word_tokenize(i))

stop_words = [stopwords.words('english')]
print(stop_words)

final_pos_words = []
for i in pos_words:
    if i not in stop_words:
        final_pos_words.append(i)
print(final_pos_words)
```

But this doesn't make any deletions
After running this:

```
final_pos_words = []
for i in pos_words:
    if i in stop_words:
        final_pos_words.append(i)
print(final_pos_words)
```

The output is []

Comment: Try: `stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))`

Comment: I tried that, but it always gives TypeError: unhashable type: 'list', at this line-  if i in stop_words: under final_pos_words

Comment: Your error is here: `pos_words.append(word_tokenize(i))`. The `word_tokenize()` method returns a list (of one word, probably), so `pos_words` contains lists, not words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe change to:

```
# import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

#Read the file
f = open('positive.txt').read()

#Tokenizing the words 
words = word_tokenize(f)

#set of predifined english stop words
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

#Filter stop words
filtered = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
print(filtered)
```

I have tried this and works for me with no error , try it and let me know about the result.

Comment: It gives the error: Unhashable type: 'list' at----> 1 if i not in stop_words: And after I change the stop_words to list, there is no change or filteration

Comment: Or try this :
    final_pos_words  =  [w for w in pos_words if not w in stop_words]

Comment: No, again, doesn't do the filtering, this is becoming really frustrating...

Comment: This works, finally,  thank you so much, do you also have any idea how to remove commas, question marks and numbers....

Comment: U W , Guess you can use Regex (re) for this purpose .or just define another set for cammas , qms , numbers and use another loop to filter them.